# Syncfusion Xamarin sfList - How to get hold of list item template instance?

Tags: syncfusion

Is it possible to directly address the View instance behind the selected item in a sfList?  Rather than using bindable properties I would prefer to just set properties directly on the views contained in the layout instance that displays the selected item (without affecting the properties of all the other itmes based on the template?
Possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

We have checked with the reported query “Need for customization of list item template” from our side. We would like to let you know that the SfListView provides support for customizing the appearance of each item with different templates based on specific constraints using DataTemplateSelector. You can refer the following UG documentation link for more information.

Documentation link: https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sflistview/viewappearance#defining-the-data-template-selector